# Offset for a calendar program

Tags: c++, calendar, offset

This program takes any user input year since 1753 and month and creates a calendar for it. However I'm having issues with the offset which is the day the month starts out on. As far as I can tell it is just the offset that is off and everything else seems to work great.
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int getMonth(int month);
int getYear(int year);
int computeOffset(int year, int month);
int numDaysYear(int year);
int numDaysMonth(int year, int month);
bool isLeapYear(int year);
void display(int year, int month, int offset);


/**********************************************************************
 * This function will call all the functions necessary to make a calendar
 * for any given month and year.
 ***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   int numDays;
   int offset;
   int month;
   int year;

   month = getMonth(month);

   year = getYear(year);

   offset = computeOffset(year, month);

   display(year, month, offset);

   return 0;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Gets the month number.
 **********************************************************************/
int getMonth(int month)
{
   cout << "Enter a month number: ";
   cin >> month;

   while ( month < 1 || month > 12)
   {
      cout << "Month must be between 1 and 12.\n"
           << "Enter a month number: ";
      cin >> month;
   }

   return month;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Gets the year.
 **********************************************************************/
int getYear(int year)
{
   cout << "Enter year: ";
   cin >> year;

   while ( year < 1753)
   {
      cout << "Year must be 1753 or later.\n"
           << "Enter year: ";
      cin >> year;
   }
   return year;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Computes the offset.
 **********************************************************************/

int computeOffset(int year, int month)
{
   int offset = 0;
   int count = year - 1753;
   for ( int iYear = 0; iYear < count; iYear++)
   {
      offset = ( offset + 365 + isLeapYear(year)) % 7;
   }

   for ( int iMonth = 1; iMonth < month; iMonth++)
   {
      offset = ( offset + numDaysMonth(year, iMonth)) % 7;
   }

   return offset;
}



/***********************************************************************
 * Computes the number of days in the given year.
 **********************************************************************/
int numDaysYear(int year)
{
   int daysYear = 365 + isLeapYear(year);
   return daysYear;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Calculates the number of days in the given month.
 **********************************************************************/
int numDaysMonth(int year, int month)
{
   int daysMonth;

   if ( month == 1)
      daysMonth = 31;
   else if ( month == 2)
   {
      if (isLeapYear(year) == true)
         daysMonth = 29;
      else
         daysMonth = 28;
   }
   else if ( month == 3)
      daysMonth = 31;
   else if ( month == 4)
      daysMonth = 30;
   else if ( month == 5)
      daysMonth = 31;
   else if ( month == 6)
      daysMonth = 30;
   else if ( month == 7)
      daysMonth = 31;
   else if ( month == 8)
      daysMonth = 31;
   else if ( month == 9)
      daysMonth = 30;
   else if ( month == 10)
      daysMonth = 31;
   else if ( month == 11)
      daysMonth = 30;
   else if ( month == 12)
      daysMonth = 31;

   return daysMonth;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Determines if given year is a leap year.
 **********************************************************************/
bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
   if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
 /**********************************************************************
 * Displays the calender table.
 **********************************************************************/
void display(int year, int month, int offset)
 {
    int dayOfWeek;
    int day;

    cout << endl;
    if ( month == 1)
       cout << "January";
    else if ( month == 2)
       cout << "February";
    else if ( month == 3)
       cout << "March";
    else if ( month == 4)
       cout << "April";
    else if ( month == 5)
       cout << "May";
    else if ( month == 6)
       cout << "June";
    else if ( month == 7)
       cout << "July";
    else if ( month == 8)
       cout << "August";
    else if ( month == 9)
       cout << "September";
    else if ( month == 10)
       cout << "October";
    else if ( month == 11)
       cout << "November";
    else if ( month == 12)
       cout << "December";


    cout << ", " << year << "\n";
    // Display month header
    cout << "  Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n";

    // Gets the correct offset width and end the line on the right
    //day of the week
    if (offset == 0)
    {
       day = 2;
       cout << setw(6);
    }
    else if (offset == 1)
    {
       day = 3;
       cout << setw(10);
    }
    else if (offset == 2)
    {
       day = 4;
       cout << setw(14);
    }
    else if (offset == 3)
    {
       day = 5;
       cout << setw(18);
    }
    else if (offset == 4)
    {
       day = 6;
       cout << setw(22);
    }
    else if (offset == 5)
    {
       day = 7;
       cout << setw(26);
    }
    else if (offset == 6)
    {
       day = 1;
       cout << setw(2);
    }
    else
       cout << "Error offset must be >= 0 and <=6\n";

    // The loop for displaying the days and ending the line in the right place
    for ( dayOfWeek = 1; dayOfWeek <= numDaysMonth(year, month); dayOfWeek++ )
    {
       cout << "  " <<  setw(2) << dayOfWeek;
       ++day;
       if (day == 8)
       {
          cout << "\n";
          day = 1;
       }
    }
    if ( day >= 2 && day <= 7)
       cout << "\n";

    return;
 }`
```

Comment: Is there a {year, month} that you know the output to be incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

New answer for old question.  Rationale for new answer:  Better tools and technology in this area.

This answer is heavily using this [free, open-source header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  I'm going to present this answer starting at the highest level, and drilling down to the lower level details.  But at all levels at no time do we have to get into detailed calendrical computations.  [`"date.h"`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) handles that for us.

Here's `main`:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    print_calendar_year(std::cout);
}
```

This just output for me:

```
January 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
                 1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31

February 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
     1  2  3  4  5  6
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 28 29

March 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
        1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 27 28 29 30 31

April 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
                 1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

May 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 29 30 31

June 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
           1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29 30

July 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
                 1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31

August 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
     1  2  3  4  5  6
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 28 29 30 31

September 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
              1  2  3
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30

October 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
                    1
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 30 31

November 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
        1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 27 28 29 30

December 2016
  S  M  T  W  T  F  S
              1  2  3
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

One could print out next year's calendar with:

```
using namespace date::literals;
print_calendar_year(std::cout, 2017_y);
```

I'll start out with the statement:

> This is a **type-safe** system.

The literal `2017_y` is an object of type `date::year`, not a simple integer.  Having types that mean `year` and `month` means it is far less likely to mix up these concepts.  Mistakes tend to be caught at compile time.

`print_calendar_year` is pretty simple:

```
void
print_calendar_year(std::ostream& os, date::year y = current_year())
{
    using namespace date;
    for (auto ym = y/jan; ym < y/jan + years{1}; ym += months{1})
    {
        print_calendar_month(os, ym);
        os << '\n';
    }
}
```

The expression `year/month` creates a type called `date::year_month` which is nothing more than a simple struct `{year, month}`.  So this function simply sets up a loop to iterate from Jan of the year y, to the next Jan, excluding the next Jan.  It is all quite readable.  And note that "bare `int`s" are not allowed.  Everything has a non-integral type.

`print_calendar_month` is where the rubber meets the road:

```
void
print_calendar_month(std::ostream& os, date::year_month ym = current_year_month())
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    os << format("%B %Y\n", sys_days{ym/1});
    os << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S\n";
    auto wd = unsigned{weekday{ym/1}};
    os << string(wd*3, ' ');
    auto const e = (ym/last).day();
    for (day d = 1_d; d <= e; wd = 0)
    {
        for (; wd < 7 && d <= e; ++wd, ++d)
            os << setw(3) << unsigned{d};
        os << '\n';
    }
}
```

`os << format("%B %Y\n", sys_days{ym/1});` is what prints out the title for each month (e.g. `January 2016`).  These are strftime-like formatting flags that will respect the localization settings of the current global `std::locale` (as much as the OS supports).

The subexpression `ym/1` creates a type `date::year_month_day` which stands for the first day of the indicated month and year.  `date::year_month_day` is a simply class holding `{year, month, day}`.

`sys_days` is a `chrono::time_point` based on `system_clock` with a precision of `days`.  `date::format` can take any precision `system_clock` `time_point` and format it using strftime-like formatting flags.  A `year_month_day` can be converted to a `sys_days` as shown.  This is a conversion from a `{year, month, day}` field type to a serial `{count of days}` type.

`os << "  S  M  T  W  T  F  S\n";` obviously prints out the day-of-the-week header for the calendar.

`auto wd = unsigned{weekday{ym/1}};` finds the day of the week of the first day of the month and converts that `weekday` into an `unsigned` using the encoding `[Sun == 0, Sat == 6]`.  [*Note:*  gcc requires the syntax `unsigned(weekday{ym/1})`.  It doesn't like the `{}` for `unsigned`. — *end note*]

`os << string(wd*3, ' ');` just prints out 3 spaces for each day before the first day of the month to pad out the first row.

`auto const e = (ym/last).day();` is a constant of type `date::day` that is equal to the last day of the month for this year and month combination.

`for (day d = 1_d; d <= e; wd = 0)`

Starting with day 1 loop until the last day of the month (inclusive) and set the `unsigned wd` back to the encoding for Sunday on each iteration.

`for (; wd < 7 && d <= e; ++wd, ++d)`:  Until you reach the end of the week or the end of the month, increment both day of the week and day of the month.

`os << setw(3) << unsigned{d};`:  Convert the day of the month to an `unsigned` and print it out right-aligned in a width a of 3 spaces.

`os << '\n';` return after printing the week.

And that's the bulk of the program!  Almost all of the tricky calendrical logic is encapsulated within these two lines of code:

```
auto wd = unsigned{weekday{ym/1}};
auto const e = (ym/last).day();
```

For completeness here are the functions to get the current `date::year` and the current `date::year_month`:

```
date::year_month
current_year_month()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    year_month_day ymd = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
    return ymd.year()/ymd.month();
}

date::year
current_year()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    year_month_day ymd = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
    return ymd.year();
}
```

Both of these simply truncate a `system_clock::time_point` returned from `system_clock::now()` to a precision of `days` using `floor`, and then convert that days-precision `time_point` to a `date::year_month_day` type.  This type then has getters for `year` and `month` to pick out the desired partial calendar types.

**Update**

Well, [TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819272/templaterex) asked a question below that I didn't want to answer at first, and then I couldn't help myself because the answer highlights how powerful `"date.h"` is to work with. ;-)

The question is:

> Can you print out the calendars in a 3x4 format like this?

```
 January 2016            February 2016           March 2016          
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                 1  2        1  2  3  4  5  6           1  2  3  4  5
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9     7  8  9 10 11 12 13     6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    14 15 16 17 18 19 20    13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    21 22 23 24 25 26 27    20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    28 29                   27 28 29 30 31      
 31                                                                  

 April 2016              May 2016                June 2016           
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                 1  2     1  2  3  4  5  6  7              1  2  3  4
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9     8  9 10 11 12 13 14     5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    15 16 17 18 19 20 21    12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    22 23 24 25 26 27 28    19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    29 30 31                26 27 28 29 30      

 July 2016               August 2016             September 2016      
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                 1  2        1  2  3  4  5  6                 1  2  3
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9     7  8  9 10 11 12 13     4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    14 15 16 17 18 19 20    11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    21 22 23 24 25 26 27    18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    28 29 30 31             25 26 27 28 29 30   
 31                                                                  

 October 2016            November 2016           December 2016       
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                    1           1  2  3  4  5                 1  2  3
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8     6  7  8  9 10 11 12     4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  9 10 11 12 13 14 15    13 14 15 16 17 18 19    11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22    20 21 22 23 24 25 26    18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 23 24 25 26 27 28 29    27 28 29 30             25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 30 31
```

Evidently so, because I wasn't about to type in all that above manually! ;-)

It requires a rewrite of `print_calendar_year` and the introduction of a a couple of new functions, most notably:

```
void
print_line_of_calendar_month(std::ostream& os, date::year_month ym, unsigned line,
                             date::weekday firstdow);
```

This function prints just one line of the calendar associated with the `year_month ym` and is the heart of this 3x4 format.

I also thought it would be fun to make this program localizable so that the desired first-day-of-week could be printed out, as well as localized names for the month and day-of-week (as much as the `std::locale` on your platform allows).

The lines are numbered [0, infinity].  Line 0 prints out the month year such as `January 2016`.  Line 1 prints out the day-of-week headers:  `Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa`.  And then lines [2, infinity] print out the days of the month.

Why infinity?

Because different months take different number of lines, so I wanted to be able to tell a `year/month` to print a next line even if it didn't need to (because another month in the quarter needed it).  So when you ask for a calendar to print out a line that it doesn't need, it just outputs the proper number of `' '` for padding purposes.

Enough intro, here's the function:

```
void
print_line_of_calendar_month(std::ostream& os, date::year_month ym, unsigned line,
                             date::weekday firstdow)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    switch (line)
    {
    case 0:
        os << left << setw(21) << format(os.getloc(), " %B %Y", sys_days{ym/1}) << right;
        break;
    case 1:
        {
        auto sd = sys_days{ym/firstdow[1]};
        for (auto const esd = sd + weeks{1}; sd < esd; sd += days{1})
        {
            auto d = format(os.getloc(), "%a", sd);
            d.resize(2);
            os << ' ' << d;
        }
        break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
        auto wd = weekday{ym/1};         // This line and the next are the "offset"
        os << string((wd-firstdow).count()*3, ' '); // referred to in the question.
        auto d = 1_d;
        do
        {
            os << setw(3) << unsigned(d);
            ++d;
        } while (++wd != firstdow);
        break;
        }
    default:
        {
        unsigned index = line - 2;
        auto sd = sys_days{ym/1};
        if (weekday{sd} == firstdow)
            ++index;
        auto ymdw = ym/firstdow[index];
        if (ymdw.ok())
        {
            auto d = year_month_day{ymdw}.day();
            auto const e = (ym/last).day();
            auto wd = firstdow;
            do
            {
                os << setw(3) << unsigned(d);
            } while (++wd != firstdow && ++d <= e);
            os << string((firstdow-wd).count()*3, ' ');
        }
        else
            os << string(21, ' ');
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

So switch on line number [0, infinity], and for each line number, do the right thing:

`0.`  Print out the Month Year heading.

This passes to `format` the `locale` of the `os` to get the localized month name.

`1.`  Print out the day-of-the-week heading.

This passes to `format` the `locale` of the `os` to get the localized weekday names, and prints the first 2 characters.  This is (unfortunately) only approximately correct when these are multi-byte characters, but this post is mostly about calendars, not Unicode.

`2.`  Print out the first week, which might be prefixed with spaces.  The number of spaces to prefix with is 3*(number of days the first of the month is past the first day of the week).  Then append days until you reach the last day of the week.  Note that weekday subtraction is always modulo 7 so you don't have to worry about the underlying encoding of the days of the weeks.  The weekdays form a circular range.  This does require something along the lines of this `do-while` as opposed to a traditional `for` when looping over all the days in a week.

`3 - infinity`.  Ah, here's the fun part.

There's a type in `"date.h"` called `year_month_weekday` which is a type storing `{year, month, weekday, unsigned}`.  This is how you might specify Mother's day:  The second Sunday of May:  `sun[2]/may/2016`.  This expression creates a struct `{2016, 5, 0, 2}` (roughly speaking).  And so if the `switch` lands here, then we are looking for the [first, last] Sunday of this month and year, where the exact index is dependent upon `line`, and whether or not we printed a Sunday out on line 2.

Also key, this library allows *any* index to be used:

```
auto ymdw = ym/firstdow[index];
```

`index` could be 1, or it could be 57.  The above line compiles and is not a run-time error.

But months can't have 57 Sundays (or Mondays or whatever)!

No problem.  You can ask if `ym/firstdow[index]` is a valid date.  This is what the next line does:

```
if (ymdw.ok())
```

If the date is valid, then you've got work to do.  Else you just print out a blank row.

If we've got work to do, then convert the `year_month_weekday` to a `year_month_day` so that you can get the day of the month from it (`d`).  And find the last day of the month:

```
auto const e = (ym/last).day();
```

Then iterate from the first day of the week to whichever comes first:  the end of the month or the last day of the week.  Print out the day of the month for each spot.  And then if you didn't end on the last day of the week, print spaces to pad out to the last day of the week.

And we're done with `print_line_of_calendar_month`!  Note that newlines were never output on this level.  Not even inter-month padding is output on this level.  Each calendar is exactly 21 `char` wide, and can be printed out to an arbitrary number of rows.

Now we need another minor utility:  What is the number of rows a calendar month needs before it starts padding with blank rows?

```
unsigned
number_of_lines_calendar(date::year_month ym, date::weekday firstdow)
{
    using namespace date;
    return ceil<weeks>((weekday{ym/1} - firstdow) +
                       ((ym/last).day() - day{0})).count() + 2;
}
```

This is the number of days in the month, plus the number of days from the first day of the week to the first of the month, plus 2 more rows for the day-of-the-week heading and the year-month heading.  Fractional weeks at the end are rounded up!

Notes:

1. The number of days from the first day of the week to the first of the month is simply: `(weekday{ym/1} - firstdow)`.
2. The number of days in the month is encoded here as `((ym/last).day() - day{0})`.  Note that `day{0}` is not a valid `day`, but can still be useful in the subtraction:  `day - day` gives a result of the `chrono::duration` `days`.  Another way to say this would have been `((ym/last).day() - day{1} + days{1})`.
3. Note that `ceil<weeks>` is used here to convert the number of `days` to number of `weeks`, rounding up to the next `weeks` if the conversion is not exact. 1 week == 1 row.  This roundup accounts for the last week that ends prior to the last day of the week.

Now `print_calendar_year` can be rewritten in terms of these primitives:

```
void
print_calendar_year(std::ostream& os, unsigned const cols = 3,
                    date::year const y = current_year(),
                    date::weekday const firstdow = date::sun)
{
    using namespace date;
    if (cols == 0 || 12 % cols != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("The number of columns " + std::to_string(cols)
                                 + " must be one of [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]");
    // Compute number of lines needed for each calendar month
    unsigned ml[12] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    for (auto& m : ml)
        m = number_of_lines_calendar(y/month{m}, firstdow);
    for (auto r = 0u; r < 12/cols; ++r) // for each row
    {
        const auto lines = *std::max_element(std::begin(ml) + (r*cols),
                                             std::begin(ml) + ((r+1)*cols));
        for (auto l = 0u; l < lines; ++l) // for each line
        {
            for (auto c = 0u; c < cols; ++c) // for each column
            {
                if (c != 0)
                    os << "   ";
                print_line_of_calendar_month(os, y/month{r*cols + c+1}, l, firstdow);
            }
            os << '\n';
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
}
```

First compute for each month how many lines it needs:

```
// Compute number of lines needed for each calendar month
unsigned ml[12] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
for (auto& m : ml)
    m = number_of_lines_calendar(y/month{m}, firstdow);
```

Then for each "calendar row", find the number of lines needed for that row by searching the proper subset of `ml`.

And then for each line, and for each "calendar column", print out the line of the corresponding calendar month for that column.

After each line print a `'\n'`.

After each calendar row, print a `'\n'`.

Note that still at no time did we need to sink down into calendrical arithmetic.  At this level we needed to know "7 days per week", "3 spaces per day" and "12/cols months per calendar row".

On macOS this driver:

```
using namespace date::literals;
std::cout.imbue(std::locale("de_DE"));
print_calendar_year(std::cout, 3, 2016_y, mon);
```

Outputs:

```
 Januar 2016             Februar 2016            März 2016          
 Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So
              1  2  3     1  2  3  4  5  6  7        1  2  3  4  5  6
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10     8  9 10 11 12 13 14     7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17    15 16 17 18 19 20 21    14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24    22 23 24 25 26 27 28    21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31    29                      28 29 30 31         

 April 2016              Mai 2016                Juni 2016           
 Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So
              1  2  3                       1           1  2  3  4  5
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10     2  3  4  5  6  7  8     6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17     9 10 11 12 13 14 15    13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24    16 17 18 19 20 21 22    20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 25 26 27 28 29 30       23 24 25 26 27 28 29    27 28 29 30         
                         30 31                                       

 Juli 2016               August 2016             September 2016      
 Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So
              1  2  3     1  2  3  4  5  6  7              1  2  3  4
  4  5  6  7  8  9 10     8  9 10 11 12 13 14     5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17    15 16 17 18 19 20 21    12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 18 19 20 21 22 23 24    22 23 24 25 26 27 28    19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31    29 30 31                26 27 28 29 30      

 Oktober 2016            November 2016           Dezember 2016       
 Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So    Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa So
                 1  2        1  2  3  4  5  6              1  2  3  4
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9     7  8  9 10 11 12 13     5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    14 15 16 17 18 19 20    12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    21 22 23 24 25 26 27    19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    28 29 30                26 27 28 29 30 31   
 31
```

Your milage may vary on how well your std::lib/OS supports localization.  But now you can print your calendar out in columns of months varying among any divisor of 12 ([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]), using any year, using any day of the week as the first day of the week, and using any locale (modulo OS support for locales).

Here's the output for `print_calendar_year(std::cout, 4, 2017_y);`

```
 January 2017            February 2017           March 2017              April 2017          
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7              1  2  3  4              1  2  3  4                       1
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14     5  6  7  8  9 10 11     5  6  7  8  9 10 11     2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21    12 13 14 15 16 17 18    12 13 14 15 16 17 18     9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28    19 20 21 22 23 24 25    19 20 21 22 23 24 25    16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 29 30 31                26 27 28                26 27 28 29 30 31       23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                                                                         30                  

 May 2017                June 2017               July 2017               August 2017         
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
     1  2  3  4  5  6                 1  2  3                       1           1  2  3  4  5
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13     4  5  6  7  8  9 10     2  3  4  5  6  7  8     6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 14 15 16 17 18 19 20    11 12 13 14 15 16 17     9 10 11 12 13 14 15    13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27    18 19 20 21 22 23 24    16 17 18 19 20 21 22    20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 28 29 30 31             25 26 27 28 29 30       23 24 25 26 27 28 29    27 28 29 30 31      
                                                 30 31                                       

 September 2017          October 2017            November 2017           December 2017       
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                 1  2     1  2  3  4  5  6  7              1  2  3  4                    1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9     8  9 10 11 12 13 14     5  6  7  8  9 10 11     3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16    15 16 17 18 19 20 21    12 13 14 15 16 17 18    10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23    22 23 24 25 26 27 28    19 20 21 22 23 24 25    17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30    29 30 31                26 27 28 29 30          24 25 26 27 28 29 30
                                                                         31
```

Comment: Is there an option to print the calendar as 4 rows by 3 colums, like in @EricNiebler 's CppCon15 talk? ([src](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/example/calendar.cpp), [slides](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/master/Keynotes/Ranges%20for%20the%20Standard%20Library/Ranges%20for%20the%20Standard%20Library%20-%20Eric%20Niebler%20-%20CppCon%202015.pptx), [video](https://youtu.be/mFUXNMfaciE))

Comment: @TemplateRex: Nope, beyond the scope of this answer.  However it wouldn't be too hard to do, and the date.h library would still handle all of the calendrical details.  I would probably start with refactoring `print_calendar_month` to call a new function `print_line_of_calendar_month`, and then iterate over quarters of the year, then over lines in the output, then over months in the quarter.  The inner most loop would call `print_line_of_calendar_month(os, ym, line)`.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  Ok, you caught me.  :-)  Couldn't resist the challenge.

Comment: Awesome addition!

Answer (score 1):

This code does not address your issue (I could not tell what the issue was) but it may be informative to contrast it with your version.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int getMonth();
int getYear();
int computeOffset(int year, int month);
int numDaysYear(int year);
int numDaysMonth(int year, int month);
bool isLeapYear(int year);
void display(int year, int month, int offset);


/**********************************************************************
 * This function will call all the functions necessary to make a calendar
 * for any given month and year.
 ***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   int offset;
   int month;
   int year;

   month = getMonth();
   year = getYear();
   offset = computeOffset(year, month);

   display(year, month, offset);

   return 0;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Gets the month number.
 **********************************************************************/
int getMonth()
{
   int month = 0;
   cout << "Enter a month number: ";
   cin >> month;

   while (month < 1 || month > 12)
   {
      cout << "Month must be between 1 and 12.\n"
           << "Enter a month number: ";
      cin >> month;
   }

   return month;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Gets the year.
 **********************************************************************/
int getYear()
{
   int year = 0;
   cout << "Enter year: ";
   cin >> year;

   while ( year < 1753)
   {
      cout << "Year must be 1753 or later.\n"
           << "Enter year: ";
      cin >> year;
   }
   return year;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Computes the offset.
 **********************************************************************/

int computeOffset(int year, int month)
{
   int offset = 0;
   int count = year - 1753;
   for (int iYear = 0; iYear < count; iYear++)
   {
      offset = (offset + 365 + isLeapYear(year)) % 7;
   }

   for (int iMonth = 1; iMonth < month; iMonth++)
   {
      offset = (offset + numDaysMonth(year, iMonth)) % 7;
   }

   return offset;
}



/***********************************************************************
 * Computes the number of days in the given year.
 **********************************************************************/
int numDaysYear(int year)
{
   return 365 + isLeapYear(year);
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Calculates the number of days in the given month.
 **********************************************************************/
int numDaysMonth(int year, int month)
{
   std::vector<int> days { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
   int daysMonth = days[month-1];

   if (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year))
   {
       daysMonth = 29;
   }

   return daysMonth;
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Determines if given year is a leap year.
 **********************************************************************/
bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
   return (year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0);
}
 /**********************************************************************
 * Displays the calender table.
 **********************************************************************/
void display(int year, int month, int offset)
 {
    int day;

    cout << endl;
    std::vector<std::string> mth { "January", "February", "March",
      "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
      "October", "November", "December" };
    cout << mth[month-1];

    cout << ", " << year << "\n";
    // Display month header
    cout << "  Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n";

    // Gets the correct offset width and end the line on the right
    // day of the week
    if (0 <= offset && offset <= 6)
    {
        day = ((offset + 1) % 7) + 1;
        cout << setw((day - 2) * 4 + 6);
    }
    else
       cout << "Error offset must be >= 0 and <=6\n";

    // The loop for displaying the days and ending the line in the right place
    for (int dayOfWeek = 1; dayOfWeek <= numDaysMonth(year, month); dayOfWeek++ )
    {
       cout << "  " <<  setw(2) << dayOfWeek;
       ++day;
       if (day == 8)
       {
          cout << "\n";
          day = 1;
       }
    }
    if (day >= 2 && day <= 7)
       cout << "\n";

    return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted over a year ago, but I do have a solution for future visitors. In the computeOffset function in the original post, the function isn't actually counting how many days have passed in all. You need to count how many years have passed, and how many days were in those years, as well as the days in the months after those years, if that makes any sense. Here is the code for my working computeOffset function:

```
int computeOffset(int month, int year)
 {
   int numDaysYear = 0;
   int yearCounter = 0;
   int monthCounter = 0;
   int months = 1  // NOT the same at the "month" variable coming in

   // This loop counts how many days have passed in the full years up to the given year
   for (int iYear = 1753; iYear < year; iYear++)
   {
      numDaysYear = numDaysYear + 365;

      if (isLeapYear(iYear))                          
         yearCounter++;
   }

   // This loop counts the days in the remaining months after all the years
   for (int iMonth = 1; iMonth < month; iMonth++)
   {
      monthCounter = monthCounter + numDaysMonth(months, year);  //MONTHS not month
      months++;
   }

   int offset = (numDaysYear + yearCounter + monthCoutner) % 7;

   return offset;
```

Hopefully this makes sense, sorry if some variables have weird names or if the style isn't what you're used to. Hope this helped!