# Create 3 month calendar with (For Loop) in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, calendar

i want to create a 3 month calendar use c++ based on input start of month-day from user input with for loop;
so i wrote this codes :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i,d; 
cout<<"Enter Start Day : ";
cin>>d;
cout<<"\nSAT SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI\n";
for (i=1;i<=d;i++) {
    if (d>1)
    cout<<"   ";
    }
for (i=1;i<=90;i++) {
    if(i<10)
cout<<i<<"   ";
else 
cout<<i<<"  ";
if ((d-1+i)%7==0)
    cout<<"\n";
if (i%30==0 && i<90) {
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"SAT SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI\n";
}
}  
  return 0;
}
```

everything is ok,1st month is currectly created,but the problem is on 2nd and 3rd month.
i want to start new month from a day after previous Month ended with.

like that :

```
SAT SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI
        27  28  29  30

**NEW MONTH**
SAT SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI
                         1
```

live code is here : http://codepad.org/iXbgy58m

what i should to do.?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40097700/576911

Comment: i am newbie in c++ can you explain how to edit the code to work correctly.?